# Garbage Collect object with one reference

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am instantiating some objects and adding them to a static list to call some methods on all of them using static methods.

After deleting all references on that object will cause the GC to remove the instance.

But in my case this object is still in my list. 
Is there any way to automatically remove them or do I have to implement a destroy method?

Comment: You must either clear the list or make it a list of weak references.

Comment: the list still references them so "all references on them " are not deleted yet ? i m no java expert tough

Comment: This is a use for WeakReference<T> in Java. Having a WeakReference to an object means that the object that is referenced can just vanish if the GC finds no other reason to keep it. Therefore you need to check before you access it, but having it in a list won't stop it from being GCed

Comment: Thank you Hot Licks ans Actorclavilis.
This is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @HotLicks can you put it as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

When a List is created, its slots will have its own location within memory. So by passing it a value from an Object e.g. (String) "Hi", you can be assured that the slot at index 0 will contain the value "Hi" of type String. When you remove a reference from an object (null), you will flag its memory location to allow its slot to be overridden. The solution is to simply access the List and remove the element.

Comment: You don't "remove" anything.  You change the value of the reference variable.  `null` is simply a different value.